# My emmet snippet of atom is not working properly

Tags: editor, atom-editor

I want to use the "Emmet" snippet of atom, but it is not working properly when I press tab after the tag name.

**Code**:

```
   'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
   'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```

but still when I apply this it is just printing simple tag like this: `<html></html>`

Answer (score 1):

CoffeeScript (and CSON, CoffeeScript Object Notation) is an indentation-sensitive languages, so you need to make sure you're using the correct indentation. When you edit `snippets.cson` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the editor will indent the second line automatically.

In the end it should look like this:

```
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'
```